# Is record.raw supported in ExtJS 5.1.3?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using ExtJS 5.1.3.

In some article I seen that record.raw is deprecated in ExtJS 5. Is it true?
I have to perform some validations based on database data. If raw data is deprecated then what is the alternative way to hold database data ?

Answer (score 1):

> record.raw is deprecated in ExtJS 5. Is it true?

It appears to have been removed completely, not just deprecated.

> what is the alternative way to hold database data ?

Force your models to not convert the values coming from server side by specifying `convert: null` in the fields:

```
Ext.define('FooBar', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'foo', convert: null},
        {name: 'bar', convert: null}
    ]
});
```

From the [doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Model):

> By default, the built in field types such as number and boolean coerce
>   string values in the raw data by virtue of their
>   Ext.data.field.Field.convert method. When the server can be relied
>   upon to send data in a format that does not need to be converted ...
>   you simply specify null for the field's convert config.